# trying to loop through inner object and changing the values based on condition

Tags: javascript, object

below is my object structure where i am trying to modify based on some values

```
export const PROJECT_PHASE = Object.freeze({
  CONCEPT: { label: 'Concept', stepNumber: 0, disabled: false, description: '' },
  SCHEMATIC: { label: 'Schematic', stepNumber: 1, disabled: false, description: '' },
  DESIGN_DEVELOPMENT: {
    label: 'Design Development',
    stepNumber: 2,
    disabled: false,
    description: ''
  },
  CONSTRUCTION_DOCUMENTS: {
    label: 'Construction Documents',
    stepNumber: 3,
    disabled: false,
    description: ''
  }
 });
```

and i am modifying the `description` value based on condition and trying to return the same object structure but could not be able to get through this and getting an error like `expression expected` at If statement.

```
Object.entries(PROJECT_PHASE).forEach(([key,value]) => (
    if(value.stepNumber === currentStepNumber){
      value.description = 'Current';
    }
  ));
```

Could any please help on this, how can i achieve modify the inner object?
many thanks !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const PROJECT_PHASE = Object.freeze({
  CONCEPT: { label: 'Concept', stepNumber: 0, disabled: false, description: '' },
  SCHEMATIC: { label: 'Schematic', stepNumber: 1, disabled: false, description: '' },
  DESIGN_DEVELOPMENT: {
    label: 'Design Development',
    stepNumber: 2,
    disabled: false,
    description: ''
  },
  CONSTRUCTION_DOCUMENTS: {
    label: 'Construction Documents',
    stepNumber: 3,
    disabled: false,
    description: ''
  }
});

const currentStepNumber = 2;

const alteredEntries = Object.entries(PROJECT_PHASE).map(([key,value]) => {
  let newValue = value;
  if(value.stepNumber === currentStepNumber){
    newValue.description = 'Current';
  }
  return [key,newValue]
});

const alteredObject = Object.fromEntries(alteredEntries);
console.log(alteredObject);
```

This will create a copy of the `PROJECT_PHASE` object modified as you want.  Note the use of `map` instead of `forEach` and taking the result and feeding it into `Object.fromEntries`

Comment: still getting eslint error `Assignment to property of function parameter 'value'.` at this line `value.description = 'Current';`

Comment: It was valid JS.  Looks like eslint is just being strict to avoid potential coding errors.  I updated the answer using a temp variable that should bypass that.

Comment: I copied the object, because presumably you want to keep the original unmodified.  Hence why it's frozen.  And you didn't have any code to reset the description to blank when it's not the current step.

Answer (score 2):

You see that error because in your forEach you are using `()` instead of `{}`

```js
PROJECT_PHASE=Object.freeze({
    CONCEPT: { label: 'Concept', stepNumber: 0, disabled: false, description: '' },
    SCHEMATIC: { label: 'Schematic', stepNumber: 1, disabled: false, description: '' },
    DESIGN_DEVELOPMENT: {
      label: 'Design Development',
      stepNumber: 2,
      disabled: false,
      description: ''
    },
    CONSTRUCTION_DOCUMENTS: {
      label: 'Construction Documents',
      stepNumber: 3,
      disabled: false,
      description: ''
    }
   });
   currentStepNumber=3
   Object.entries(PROJECT_PHASE).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    if(value.stepNumber === currentStepNumber){
      value.description = 'Current';
    }
   });

console.log(PROJECT_PHASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cab use this way, there is a error in your code. I am using currentStepNumber is 3 here

```
  Object.entries(PROJECT_PHASE).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    if(value.stepNumber === 3){
      value.description = 'Current';
    }
  });
```